# Remote Debugging in Delphi XE8 and Delphi 10 Seattle - How can I use a fixed remote directory?

Tags: delphi, remote-debugging, delphi-xe8, delphi-10-seattle

To debug remotely with Delphi, now that the PAServer is normally used, one usually follows the following preliminary steps, as outlined on the online docwiki:

- Create a remote profile inside your ide, in my case I'm calling it `win7vm`, this contains the IP address of the remote system, and a few options, and the PAServer connection password, but as far as I can see, it doesn't contain any context information like "I want to use the following remote folders".
- The remote folders that are usually used to contain my target executable are usually a subdirectory underneath the scratch directory. If I configure the main scratch directory to be `c:\scratch`, and my remote profile was named `win7vm` and my project is name `project1`, then the IDE and PA Server are going to compile and deliver my executable to `c:\scratch\win7vm\project1` and run it from there.

What I actually want is to have my executable be delivered to and run right in @c:\scratch@.  I have a gigabyte of supporting files that all need to be in the same directory as my main executable and I don't want to have 8 copies of these supporting files. So, can this be done? Can I make PA Server NOT create a sub-folder with the name of my project and another for the name of my session? If so, is this done inside the paserver.config file, or on my client side, or somewhere else?

Update: I tried to change the Remote Path in the `Project -> Deployment`, but it does not work to use a relative path here. For example, change it to `..\..\` and the working directory in Project Options to `..\..\`, but it still only delivers my executable to the folder `c:\scratch\win7vm\project1` instead of directly into `c:\scratch\`

Update 2: It appears you *can't* do what I want, which is have the scratch directory be the main folder, and NOT create any sub-folders per-profile and per-project, and that if you don't like working in a scratch sub-folder, you should just set Absolute Remote Paths in Deployment and Absolute working folder in your project's Run options, and you should turn off restricted mode, however this means that the entire VM or machine you are remotely debugging can be manipulated by the PAServer, which is also hardly ideal. I believe that having a fixed root scratch folder would be a safer and more flexible way of working, so I'm leaving this question open, hoping to find an effective way to achieve a safe but flexible remote debugging technique.

Comment: Just an idea: use [symlinks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx) on the target machine.

Comment: I think I'm trying to violate its "restricted mode". I just used an absolute path and now I see this: `[PAClient Error] Error: E0006 Copying file(s) to directory outside 'C:\scratch\win7vm\' is not allowed; PAServer is running in restricted mode` -- I need to add `--unrestricted` to the launch arguments I send to paserver.exe -- This restricted mode is a fantastic safety feature in the paserver tool, I'm not annoyed, I'm impressed. Good job, whoever designed this.

Comment: Interesting and I agree, good job.

Comment: Replying to your update 2: you can have a symlink directory pointing to its ancestor directory: `mkdir c:\scratch\win7vm && mklink /d c:\scratch\win7vm\projct1 c:\scratch`. This should make all project1 files go to `c:\scratch`. However this creates endless recursion in the file system so be careful.

Comment: It seems to work with a symlink pointing outside of paserver's directory, too, even in restricted mode (when the symlink itself is created within paserver's directory). So the endless recursion is not necessary, either.